# What function does the Inductor and Resistor serve?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

The image attached is the circuit of a SMPS with primary side regulation. I am not sure about the purpose of inductor L1 and resistor R5 in this circuit. I figured it has something to do with noise reduction. Is it to reduce ripple caused by the full bridge rectifier or reduce the switching noise from the MOSFET? Would appreciate a concrete answer with frequencies being attenuated.

[image: SMPS]

Comment: Well, L1 is pretty obvious as a DC-link filter. Not sure about R5 though. It's not for discharging C4/C5 or snubbing L1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L1 reduces the noise generated by the converter. If too much electrical noise gets into the mains cord the product will fail EMC.

L1 is far too small to reduce mains frequency artifacts. If L1 had enough inductance to attenuate mains frequency harmonic noise, the small cheap SMPS could double in size. Passive mains harmonic filtering is not cheap and when done properly, it involves a network of inductors and capacitors.

Your resistor damps unwanted resonances in L1. It may have been added when a peak occured in a conducted EMC plot .